# How to give permission to SQL services?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I'm developing a program in c# and using SQL server 2008 as database everything works fine on the developer machine.

But in client machine when I try to backup the database it only allows to save backup of DB on D:\, E:\, ... directories

When I try to save the backup of the DB on C:\ it only allows in Backup folder of SQL server installation folder

My question is how to give write access or allow SQL service to save backup of DB in any directory.

I know some stuff about Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services but I dont know how exactly deal with it.

error snippet

```
Cannot open backup device 'C:\User\Saleh\Documents\12.bak'. Operating system error 5 (failed to rerieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need write permissions on the client machine for folders that you want to write to. You need to ask the client to either log in as an admin or give you write permissions on the specific folders.

It works on your developer machine because you are possibly a local admin on it and therefore have write access on all the folders.

Comment: error snippet Cannot open backup device 'C:\User\Saleh\Documents\12.bak'. Operating system error 5 (failed to rerieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).

Comment: OK but thats YOUR user area, only an administrator or you can write there, you should create a directory for the file that you can all get to - its safest that way

Comment: but i want user to be able to save backup in any directory

Comment: @Musa: To be able to write in a directory, a user needs write permissions to it.